# onkeypress event is not working in opera mini

Tags: javascript, opera-mini

Is there any way by which I can enable onkeypress event in opera mini for mobile?
its working in almost all browser but not in opera mini.

My code is:

```
 <pre>
    <script type="text/javascript">        
    function doCheck(field) {
      if (isNaN(document.getElementById(field).value)) {
        alert('This is not a number! Please enter a valid number before submitting the form.');
        document.getElementById(field).focus();
        document.getElementById(field).select(); 
        return false;
      }else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function abc(){         
      var a;
      a = document.getElementById('inp').value;        
      if(isNaN(a)){
        alert("you can write only numbers");
        document.getElementById('inp').value = "";
      }
    }
    </script>        
  </pre>
```

Comment: Not related to answer, but your `<pre>` tag should not enclose your `<script>` tag.

Comment: Where is your `onkeypress` event trigger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as i know, [Opera Mini only has limited JS support](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/javascript-support-in-opera-mini-4/) (and `onKeyPress` isn't one of them)

Comment: Actually i want to get only numeric value from textbox..
not any character or symbol..
Is there any way to do this..

Thank you..

Comment: apparently you don't get what i mean. please read the article again.